# Handling UI in Xamarin.IOS

Tags: xcode, xamarin.ios, xamarin-studio

I am a new iphone developer using xamarin studios.I wanted to know if i need to learn objective-c for handling the ui in xcode?
For example,i have made a UIView(subview) in my viewcontroller(.xib) and i need to generate many such similar UIViews on same button click.
So do I need to write the event code in xcode .h or .m file or in the .cs file in xamarin studios?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you do not need to learn Obj-C.  It's helpful to be able to READ it, because Apple's samples and docs (as well as a lot of reference material on the web) are written in Obj-C.  But you can create your UI using XCode's design tools or directly in code with C# without having to write any Obj-C code.

Answer (score 2):

The views can be created in xib using interface builder or by code using c#, for the event you have to do it in cs file like in csharp.

Answer (score 1):

No, the Objective-C .h/m. files that Xamarin Studio generates in the Xcode project are just stubs mirroring the actions and outlets on your exported C# classes, so that Xcode UI designer (which only understands Obj-C) can connect to them. You can add outlets/actions to these stubs using Xcode's control-drag connections system, and those will be synced back to C#, but anything more advanced added to the obj-c stubs will be ignored. You must write your actual implementations in C#.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to learn Objective-C, although it will be helpful. It's more important to be familiar with the Cocoa Touch frameworks, particularly UIKit; this knowledge is no less useful when developing with Xamarin.